# Show that for each composite integer n, there exists a prime $p$ dividing $n$ (with $p\leq n^{1/2}$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a composite integer. Show that there exists a prime $p$ dividing $n$, with $p\leq n^{1/2}$.

$n$ is a composite integer so $n= ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are larger than $1$, let $p$ be a prime, suppose $p^2 \leq a^2 \leq ab = n$, because $p \ | \ a$ and $a \ | \ n$ then $p \ | \ n$. Hence, $p\leq n^{1/2}$.
Am I right about this?

Comment: No, you assumed the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, except that you should really say, $n=ab$ where $1<a\leq b$.  Well, I see what Mars is saying.  You have the idea right, but you're not stating it well.  Instead of saying "Let $p$ be a prime," you mean to say, "There is a prime $p|a$ so $p^2\leq a^2 $ etc.

Comment: See the _Sieve of Eratosthenes_.

Comment: Hint: it's the multiplicative analog of: either $\,a\,$ or $\,b\,$ is $\le $ their average (arithmetic mean) $\,n = (a+b)/2,\,$ by replacing arithmetic with geometric mean $\,n = (ab)^{1/2}\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is composite then $n=ab$ either $a<n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ or $b<n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ since otherwise $n>n$. How  does this relate to primes?